# How is Indonesia blocking images in e2ee applications?

Tags: http, proxy, end-to-end-encryption

Indonesia's minister in communication and informatics supposedly blocked the sending of images and videos through social media from 22nd May until 25th May, in order to prevent hoaxes from spreading too rapidly.

I had a discussion with my friends on how this works, and we (sort of) concluded that it's the HTTP request that they block when the content type is an image or video.

Now that made me think, because some of my friends can't send photos in private messages too, does this mean e2ee doesn't hide content type?

Comment: What were you using to send messages? How are the images being sent? Are you linking to image sites in order to send images? Details really matter.

Comment: The simpler conclusion is that how you were sending the images was blocked and not the transmission was blocked. Please look up how the block was implemented: https://netblocks.org/reports/indonesia-blocks-social-media-as-election-protests-escalate-XADE7LBg